# Python show a two-dimensional PDF function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Is there any elegant way of showing a two-dimensional PDF function?

I have a function F(x,y) and I want to illustrate it.

Here is one solution:

Generate a meshgrid and calculate the value of each point, then use imshow()

```
     1 1.5   2 2.5   3 3.5
    -----------------------
  1| 0   0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5
1.5| 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.8
  2| 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.8
2.5| 0 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4   1
  3| 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.8
```

However I don't know whether to use np.vstack or np.meshgrid to generate the "meshgrid".

Can anybody tell me how to draw the map above? Or provide a more "elegant" way to do it?

## Feedback

The solution below works perfect.
It yields the figure like this:
[image: Distribution]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `meshgrid` to make the coordinates:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(1, 3.5, 6)
y = np.linspace(1, 3, 5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

And then apply your `F` at each point:

```
z = np.array([F(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = z.reshape(X.shape)
```

Now create a surface plot something like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('F(X, Y)')
plt.show()
```

You can of course use `imshow` aswell, if you prefer to represent the `F` using colour rather than using a 3D plot.  It doesn't make much sense to use meshgrid if you're going to use imshow though.

Comment: It's an elegant solution to this. However I'm new to python and I don't know the `zip` function. Can tell me what it is in a sentence? This can greatly accelerate my process of reading the reference.

Comment: It pairs together sequences, for example  `zip([1,2,3], 'abc')`
yields `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`